# Passing struct parameter in template method c++

Tags: c++, class, templates

I have a problem with passing parameter to class template

```
struct Car {
    int id;
    char *model;
    int date;
    int cost;
};

template <class T>
class Set
{
private:
    int *a;
    int _size;
    map<int, T> data;
public:

    //some methods before

    void insert(T x)
    {

        int num;
        if (std::is_same<T, Car>::value)
            num = x.id;
        if (num >= 0 && num < (_size << 5))
            throw "Element is out of set size!";
        a[num / 32] = a[num / 32] | (1 << (num % 32));
        if (std::is_same<T, Car>::value)
            data.insert(make_pair(num, x));
    }
};
```

My `insert` method should accept both `int` type and `Car` struct. But Visual Studio says that I have compilation error at `num = x.id;` that `x` should be a class, struct or union. I could pass pointers to this function, but I won't be able to pass integers like `class.insert(5)`. How can I solve it or how I can make method to accept both pointers to struct and regular variables without making another specification to one of the types?

Comment: `std::is_same` doesn't work like that. You need SFINAE or `if constexpr `.

Comment: As per comment above. When you're trying to use `Set<int>`, compiler generates version of code with (let's say) `T` replaced by `int`. Now your part of insert function that is referencing to `x.id` simply doesn't compile because `int` type don't have any fields, especially id. You should use template specialization to solve that problem.

Comment: If the class is going to be that small, and since the template parameter is on the class, you could also just use a template specialization.

Comment: Or, as an alternative, throw away this `Set<T>` and use `std::unordered_set<T>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is a problem a lot of people struggle with. Let's look at your template method snipped:

```
void insert(T x)
{
    int num;
    if (std::is_same<T, Car>::value)
        num = x.id;
    //...
```

The problem here is that `if` statement semantically evaluated at run time  (even if compiler can optimize the branch away because it will know the value at compile time) and thus, compiler needs to 'pretend' to generate code for both branches. On a side note, when branch is not taken, your `num` remains unitialized, which is undefined behavior.

In your case it means that even when `T` is not `Car`, semantically code still needs to be generated for `num = x.id`. Obviously, `int.id` is not a valid statement.

To solve this problem with C++17 you would use `if constexpr`:

```
if constexpr (std::is_same<T, Car>::value) //...
```

`Constexpr if`s are guaranteed to be evaluated at compile time, and code belonging to not taken branch would not be evaluated.

In the pre-C++17 world, you usually can use either tag dispatch or SFINAE. I always prefer tag dispatch, as I think it is way more straightforward than SFINAE. Tag dispatch relies on using function overload, and in your case would be something like (since it's unclear what your code would do when passed `int`, I will pretend you need to set `num` to int passed:

```
int get_id(const Car& car) {
    return car.id;
}

int get_id(int v) {
    return v;
}

void insert(const T& t) {
    int num = get_id(t);
    // ...
```

Please note, in this particular case it is not even tag dispatch, as the case is very simple.

Comment: Isn't this just plain old overload resolution instead of tag dispatch?

Comment: @PasserBy Yeah it is, there's no tag involved here.

Answer (score 1):

Consider this simplified example:

```
template <typename T> 
struct foo { 
    T t;
    void bar() {
        if (std::is_same<T,Car>) { std::cout << t.id; }
    }
};
```

Now you have to remember that template instantiation happens at compile time, ie for `foo<Car>` the compiler creates a

```
 struct foo<Car> {  
     Car t;
     void bar() {
          if (true) { std::cout << t.id; }
     }
 };
```

so far so good, but when you instantiate the same template for `int` you get

```
 struct foo<int> {  
     int t;
     void bar() {
          if (false) { std::cout << t.id; }
     }
 };
```

the problem is that even though the condition is always false, the code still needs to compile. `int` has no `id`, hence your code fails to compile.

There are several ways to solve your problem. You could use SFINAE (which can be a bit confusing if you are not used to it, like me ;) , `if constexpr` (which avoids that not taken branches must be valid) or simply explicitly provide the specializations you need.

Answer (score -1):

To make that line even compile you'd have to use `if constexpr`:

```
        if constexpr(std::is_same<T, Car>::value) num = x.id;
```

But note that as of your current code, otherwise `num` remains uninitialized (and used in the following line nevertheless).

The most reasonable way, if you want to be able to `insert` arguments of types `T`, `Car` and `int`, is probably to spread the functionality between the three overloads:

```
void insert(T x);
void insert(Car x);
void insert(int x);
```

And additionally specialize the template for both types `Car` and `int`, otherwise it won't compile.

Or did you mean that the `Set` should actually accept elements of all types? Then it is a much trickier type. First of all, the `insert` method itself should be templated:

```
template<typename T> void insert(T x);
```

while the class itself, most likely, should not:

```
class Set;
```

(Then in the templated `insert` you can use everything that has been said about `if constexpr` in this thread.)

Next, the underlying container should accept values of *all* types, which means you'll need to use something like `map<int, std::any>` (BTW, why `map`? Order-by-ids is not probably very consistent if you store cars intermixed with integers. You can use `unordered_map` here, or even `unordered_set`, with your own multityped hash function.)

And last but not the least, it will take a while to craft a minimally consistent scheme to actually *retrieve* stored values. The major problem here, is you'll have to store them type-erased, so you'll need to somehow recall the actual type of a stored value — in a not-totally-unelegant way.

Is that what you're trying to build?

Comment: You do not need to specialize the template with your code sample.

Comment: @user463035818 Excuse me?

Comment: "[...] is probably to spread the functionality between the three overloads: [...] And additionally specialize the template for both types Car and int, otherwise it won't compile." if you specialize you dont need the overloads

Comment: Excuse me? If you don't specialize, you'll have two identical `insert`s in `Set<Car>` (and in `Set<int>` as well) and compiler will complain, won't it?